# BackupExec storage error after migration

Tags: migration, backupexec

I've migrated my BackupExec 15 installation to a 2016 Server by following [this](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.100001807) Document. If I try to run a Job I get an error saying something like

> No writable idle devices are available

The target device is a B2D drive on a Synology NAS accessed by iSCSI. In the Windows Explorer the Drive is available and accessible, BackupExec says "Online". I've also checked (an re-set) the read-only setting in the details.

On the old server everything ran like a charm. What is BE trying to tell me?